# Visual Studio 2017 CMake project no debug symbols

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Failed to debug app inside VS2017 using built-in support for CMake in VS2017:

> Module was compiled without symbols

Project configuration is set as x64-Debug:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; // breakpoint set here is ignored
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project (FuelTrip)

add_executable(Main main.cpp)
```

launch.vs,json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "${buildRoot}\\Main.exe",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "${buildRoot}\\Main.exe",
      "type": "debug"
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {},
  "version": "0.2.1"
}
```

Configuration output:

Command Line: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\Amadeusz\CMakeBuilds\994008b2-a9d0-383b-b166-558e527025e3\install\x64-Debug"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\@Projekty@\Others\FuelTrip"

Compilation output:

[1/2] C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe    -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Main.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Main.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Main.dir/main.cpp.obj -c D:/@Projekty@/Others/FuelTrip/main.cpp
  [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe -g   CMakeFiles/Main.dir/main.cpp.obj  -o Main.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libMain.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

Someone had similar issue?

Comment: What's the command line that's generated by CMake to build the project?

Comment: @IInspectable Added configuration and compilation output in question

Comment: You aren't using the default compiler (i.e. MSVC or Clang). Is this intentional?

Comment: @IInspectable Its not intentional. Apparently its default setting

Comment: Apparently, this is by design ([Visual Studio 2017's CMake integration uses MinGW compiler](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/101739/visual-studio-2017s-cmake-integration-uses-mingw-c.html)). If you want to use the MSVC toolchain instead, add the following `"cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=cl.exe -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=cl.exe"` to your CMakeSettings.json.

Comment: To clarify, it's not by design that it doesn't use `cl.exe`, but if you have another compiler in your `PATH` before `cl.exe`, CMake uses that one when it configures.